# Загрузка данных формы в потоке

Tags: c#, winforms, потоки-данных

Не могу разобраться с потоками. При загрузки формы загружаются данные с SQL сервера (справочники и т.п.), проблема в том что форма из-за этого открывается слишком долго. Как сделать эти выборки в отдельном потоке, желательно каким-нибудь уведомлением что мол "идет загрузка ... " (но не обязательно).
У меня на данный момент сделано так:

```
public partial class FormData: Form
    {
        public FormData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadDictionary();  // метод загрузки справочников
            loadData();  // метод загрузки данных на форму   
        }

....
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, я бы не советовал делать это в конструкторе класса, так как в случае исключения в конструкторе, восстановить нормальную работу программы будет невозможно.

Что касается самой загрузки - [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), например.

Comment: try .. catch уже разве не работает ?
а пример можно ?

Comment: Пример в статье MSDN, очень и очень развёрнутый, с прогрессом и прочими прелестями.

try...catch работает, производительность падает, если будете ловить базовый Exception, а если не будете, всё равно существует шанс на UnhandledException свалиться, что в случае с конструктором - фатально.

Comment: Попробовал через обычный Thread вызвать метод который нужно в потоке делать. Но выходит ошибка - Недопустимая попытка вызвать MetaData при закрытом устройстве чтения.

Может в самом методе ошибка, вот сам метод http://pastebin.com/GSsMDj9V